How is VisionOS RealityKit calculating its rotation (roll pitch yaw)?
Problem
Apple has an object for tracking the wrist such as anchor.originFromAnchorTransform and on this object, there is a rotation field that is protected so I can't access it, but it gets printed if you print anchor like this. I'm trying to reproduce the values that HandAnchor has calculated from the transformation matrix but I can never get what the HandAnchor has calculated
HandAnchor(
 chirality: left,
 id: F37E231E-ED08-4E3A-8888-AD99CA814F70,
 isTracked: true, 
 originFromAnchorTransform:
   <translation=(-0.124833 0.765254 -0.135481) 
   rotation=(76.86° -119.53° 144.82°)>,
 handSkeleton: HandSkeleton(jointCount: 27))

Data
Here is the original 4x4 matrix. Note: Apple uses column major, so each array is a column.
simd_float4x4([
[-0.08531584, 0.13101268, -0.987703, 0.0],
[0.9765112, -0.18586183, -0.10900249, 0.0],
[-0.19785702, -0.97380245, -0.1120784, 0.0],
[-0.12483275, 0.7652545, -0.13548124, 1.0]])

These are the numbers I keep calculating based on the code below
(-96.56549, 11.411671, 94.99314)
(94.99314, 11.411671, -96.56549)
(-173.70236, 6.522802, -101.485016)

but the expected is
(76.86° -119.53° 144.82°)
Code
I've tried a bunch of different formulas, but no matter what, I can't get the same calculations that it's getting.
  func getIntrinsicRotation(_ anchor: HandAnchor) -> (Float, Float, Float) {
      let rotationMatrix = extractUpperLeft3x3(from: anchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
      
      // Compute yaw, pitch, roll from rotationMatrix in intrinsic order
      let sy = sqrt(rotationMatrix[0, 0] * rotationMatrix[0, 0] + rotationMatrix[1, 0] * rotationMatrix[1, 0])
      let singular = sy < 1e-6 // If singularity is detected
      
      let yaw: Float
      let pitch: Float
      let roll: Float

      if !singular {
          yaw = atan2(rotationMatrix[1, 0], rotationMatrix[0, 0])
          pitch = atan2(-rotationMatrix[2, 0], sy)
          roll = atan2(rotationMatrix[2, 1], rotationMatrix[2, 2])
      } else {
          yaw = atan2(-rotationMatrix[1, 2], rotationMatrix[1, 1])
          pitch = atan2(-rotationMatrix[2, 0], sy)
          roll = 0
      }

      // Convert radians to degrees
      let yawDegrees = yaw * 180 / .pi
      let pitchDegrees = pitch * 180 / .pi
      let rollDegrees = roll * 180 / .pi
      
      return (yawDegrees, pitchDegrees, rollDegrees)
  }
  
  func getExtrinsicRotation(_ anchor: HandAnchor) -> (Float, Float, Float) {
      let rotationMatrix = extractUpperLeft3x3(from: anchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
      
      // Compute roll, pitch, yaw from rotationMatrix in extrinsic order
      let sy = sqrt(rotationMatrix[0, 0] * rotationMatrix[0, 0] + rotationMatrix[1, 0] * rotationMatrix[1, 0])
      let singular = sy < 1e-6 // If singularity is detected
      
      let roll: Float
      let pitch: Float
      let yaw: Float

      if !singular {
          roll = atan2(rotationMatrix[1, 2], rotationMatrix[0, 2])
          pitch = atan2(-rotationMatrix[2, 2], sy)
          yaw = atan2(rotationMatrix[2, 1], rotationMatrix[2, 0])
      } else {
          roll = atan2(-rotationMatrix[1, 0], rotationMatrix[0, 0])
          pitch = atan2(-rotationMatrix[2, 0], sy)
          yaw = 0
      }

      // Convert radians to degrees
      let rollDegrees = roll * 180 / .pi
      let pitchDegrees = pitch * 180 / .pi
      let yawDegrees = yaw * 180 / .pi
      
      return (rollDegrees, pitchDegrees, yawDegrees)
  }
  
  func getRotation(_ anchor: HandAnchor) -> (Float, Float, Float) {
    let rotationMatrix = extractUpperLeft3x3(from: anchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
    
    // Compute roll, pitch, yaw from rotationMatrix
    let sy = sqrt(rotationMatrix[0, 0] * rotationMatrix[0, 0] + rotationMatrix[1, 0] * rotationMatrix[1, 0])
    let singular = sy < 1e-6 // If singularity is detected

    let x: Float
    let y: Float
    let z: Float

    if !singular {
        x = atan2(rotationMatrix[2, 1], rotationMatrix[2, 2])
        y = atan2(-rotationMatrix[2, 0], sy)
        z = atan2(rotationMatrix[1, 0], rotationMatrix[0, 0])
    } else {
        x = atan2(-rotationMatrix[1, 2], rotationMatrix[1, 1])
        y = atan2(-rotationMatrix[2, 0], sy)
        z = 0
    }

    // Convert radians to degrees
    let rollDegrees = x * 180 / .pi
    let pitchDegrees = y * 180 / .pi
    let yawDegrees = z * 180 / .pi
    
    return (rollDegrees, pitchDegrees, yawDegrees)
  }


You can find rotation order in RealityKit definition

I'm glad you found the solution, and I'm also figuring out the same problem. You can check my code base on the formulation from:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#cite_note-nasa-rotation-1

here are the code:
extension simd_quatf {
    func convertToEulerAngles() -> SIMD3<Float> {
        let q = self
        let sinr_cosp = 2 * (q.real * q.imag.z + q.imag.x * q.imag.y)
        let cosr_cosp = 1 - 2 * (q.imag.z * q.imag.z + q.imag.x * q.imag.x)
        
        // 翻滚角 又叫 bank, 围绕Z轴
        var roll = atan2(sinr_cosp, cosr_cosp)
        
        let sinp = 2 * (q.real * q.imag.x - q.imag.y * q.imag.z)
        // 俯仰角 围绕X轴
        var pitch: Float
        if abs(sinp) >= 1 {
            pitch = copysign(.pi / 2, sinp)
        } else {
            pitch = asin(sinp)
        }
        
        let siny_cosp = 2 * (q.real * q.imag.y + q.imag.z * q.imag.x)
        let cosy_cosp = 1 - 2 * (q.imag.x * q.imag.x + q.imag.y * q.imag.y)

        // 偏航角 又叫 heading 围绕Y轴
        var yaw = atan2(siny_cosp, cosy_cosp)
        
        // convert to degrees
        roll = roll * 180 / .pi
        pitch = pitch * 180 / .pi
        yaw = yaw * 180 / .pi

        return SIMD3<Float>(yaw, pitch, roll)
    }
}

  let matrix = simd_float4x4([
    [-0.08531584, 0.13101268, -0.987703, 0.0],
    [0.9765112, -0.18586183, -0.10900249, 0.0],
    [-0.19785702, -0.97380245, -0.1120784, 0.0],
    [-0.12483275, 0.7652545, -0.13548124, 1.0]])
  let transform = Transform(matrix: matrix)
  print(transform.rotation.convertToEulerAngles())

and the code print
SIMD3(-119.529915, 76.85623, 144.8203)
as my return order is yaw (about Y axis), pitch (about X axis), roll (about Z axis). So it is the same as you expected.

That's funny because the same code was generated by ChatGPT on 11.07.2024 while I was looking for some robust way to extend CMAttitude.

Can you explain what the copysign line is for? In my opinion, it changes nothing. You must also be aware of conventions since Apple uses YXZ order because the X and Y axes are swapped in CMQuaternion representation due to Y being up on screen and X being right.

I am also curious how you resolved the rotation axes singularity (aka gimbal lock) issue. Have you decided just to not handle near 90 degrees on the pitch?

@iyzkov That's really funny, because I generate this code by ChatGPT either. But it not work in the first place, and I don't know how to edit it. So I tried to learn quaternion and euler angles, and it took me almost a month to get it work.
For the copysign part, I think it will solve the gimbal lock issue, but not tested  yet. I will post more info after I learn more details.
CMQuaternion this is the first time come to my mind, but it seems interesting to me.

After doing every single combination of XYZ, YXZ, ZXY.... etc, etc. I figured out that the order was YZX and instead of people roll, pitch, yaw. It's pitch, yaw, roll. I haven't figured out why I have to negate the pitch and roll to get it to be the same value as the HandAnchor though.
  func getRotationYZX(_ anchor: HandAnchor) -> (Float, Float, Float) {
    let rotationMatrix = extractUpperLeft3x3(from: anchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
    let roll = atan2(-rotationMatrix[0, 1], rotationMatrix[1, 1])
    let pitch = atan2(rotationMatrix[2, 1], sqrt(rotationMatrix[2, 2] * rotationMatrix[2, 2] + rotationMatrix[2, 0] * rotationMatrix[2, 0]))
    let yaw = atan2(rotationMatrix[2, 0], rotationMatrix[2, 2])
    
    let rollDegrees = roll * 180 / .pi
    let pitchDegrees = pitch * 180 / .pi
    let yawDegrees = yaw * 180 / .pi
    
    return (-pitchDegrees, yawDegrees, -rollDegrees)
  }


BWT , there is a many EA representing same rotation.

what does EA mean?

EA == Euler Angles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

You can easily get the Euler angles via SceneKit's SCNNode:
var n = SCNNode()
n.simdTransform = anchor.originFromAnchorTransform
let eu = n.simdEulerAngles

or other conversions
let quaternion = n.simdOrientation
let axisANgle = n.simdRotation

